# Moving .net source into multiple components from one in RTC

Tags: .net, rtc

I have a project that is currently arrange into one component in one stream.
But the reality is that these projects could easily be broken out into multiple components in the one stream.  This would make it easier to build applications and apply unit tests in the build definition and so on.

This is my current structure

```
OriginalProj Stream
      |
OrigProjComponent
      |
   Source
      |
   Components (That is how it is labeled in source... Not an RTC component)
      |
   Solutions 
   source  -----------------------------------------------------------------
     |               |          |          |            |           |       
   Project A     Project B  Project C  Project D   Project E    Project N
```

I want to have multiple components organized with a couple of the projects

```
OrigProjComponent-------------------------------------------------------------
       |                      |                    |                     |
     Component A             Component B           Component C          Component----D
      |        |              |         |           |         |          |       |   |
   Project A  Project B    Project C  ProjectD    Project E Project F  Project G H   I
```

How can I do that from the component that I already have?  If you have a link or something I look at that will help me with this (IBM's notoriously bad documentation included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed important to respect an optimal size for component.
That size is described in "[Collaborative Lifecycle Management 2012 Sizing Report](https://jazz.net/library/article/814)", and more recently in the "[Welcome to the Deployment wiki and community](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/WebHome) ".

> We recommend 100K files and folders in a single component and if you have more files to split them into multiple components

The split process itself is described [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/118228/move-files-and-folders-between-components-and-retain-history), and this Work Item [Enhancement 56504 "Move files and folders between components and retain history"](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=56504) (not yet fully implemented)

The current workaround, to move and retain history, is:

> - create a dummy project and share it into your component.
> - do a regular move of the things you want to move into that dummy project
> - check-in your changes and close (or complete) the change sets.
> - use the Team->MoveInRepository to move the dummy project to the destination component
> - move the files/directories to where you really want them to go within the destination component.
> - check-in your changes
> - do a "Team->RemoveInRepository (or 'Delete From Repository')" on the (now empty) dummy project (unless you want to just keep it around for a subsequent move)

Comment: Could I get more information on this.  I don't think What I am doing is working.   Could you link to a step by step tutorial on how to get this done.  I have no idea why IBM has to make there stuff so cryptic and hard to use.

Comment: @DmainEvent unfortunately, that is all the procedure I have right now.

Comment: Actually, I think it worked, just not the way I expected it to. But I will continue to work with it, and once I get everything to work I will give you the check mark.